Calculating worst case blocking time for Priority Ceiling Protocol/Stack Resource Policy

I do not understand on how the process to calculate the blocking time for the tasks. The only answers I managed to get was 4 for task 1 (which I am not sure if it is even correct), 0 for tasks 4 and 6. I am not sure on how to calculate for the other tasks
This is the understanding I have to calculate the worst case blocking time.
First identify all the lower priority tasks and the resources used by them
For the resources identified in step 1, check if the resource ceiling is equal to or higher than the task I am evaluating for
Get the maximum Resouce Access Time (RAT) value and thats the blocking time

Is this from a specific textbook or paper?  Did they include definitions?  I would have assumed that Task 1 went first (unless it wasn't allowed to interrupt), so it had 0 block -- but Task 3 would have to wait for Task 2, which wouldn't even start until Task 1 finished, so that Task 2 would have a best-case of 8 delay.  Worst case would be that Task 2 used the resources in the "wrong" order, and blocked Task 3 for (4+3) instead of just max(4+3), or that tasks started too optimistically and deadlocked.
